# Testing remote access with ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have the following command to check if remote client permits to log  in with ssh without pass

```
 ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no \
     $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Command is executed and if `permission=no` I am setting permissions at the rest of code. By the way "permissin denied message is sent to /dev/null". But when the second time I execute my command, this time `permission=yes` and I must be log in to machine but it hangs of because I think there is no error or output. Cause I tried it like when I got the permission in code;

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP
```

this time works.

So how can i arrange it to send error message for the first time and not to sent at rest

EDIT: As I can explain simple, my questin is that, say i have a command in my script that is possible to give error first time I run my script  so i dont want to see erorrs and output and I run it as

```
command 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null(it is in my script)
```

when i run script second time, the command will not give errors and output becaue i made some operations so it does no error.but when it is run second time it hangs becaue of /dev/null(i think so). because when it runs without /dev/null it works fine

Comment: There is no output or error message in the first command because you send both STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null, which is the data sink where everything is thrown away.

I don't understand the rest of your question. Please clarify.

Comment: @mpe yes no error messages in first cause i send.but in defaault it must give a permission denied message so i sent to dev null.at the rest of the script i had permissions.when i run script second time. the command hangs because there is no error message cause i had the certificates to reach the client.so i need the second time work command

Comment: Note: `> /dev/null 2>& 1` is common idiom for `1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null`.  In rare cases I will use `>& - 2>& -`; this will actually close fd 1 and 2 -- but use with caution - not all commands like that.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld thanks for > /dev/null 2>& 1. I know it but i thougt as the error must be from that.I tried everyrhing even not logical:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a command to be executed on the other side.

I typically use `:` or `echo ok`. The first one should not produce any output, and I like error messages.

```
remote_account=$REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP 

ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $remote_account : 2> /dev/null
```

or

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $remote_account echo ok | grep ok
```

The rest of your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do.

If you don't specify a command, `ssh` will create a shell, but all your output is directed `/dev/null`, so you don't see anything. It looks like it's hanged, but it's not, it's just waiting for you to type comamnds. If you type `exit` + ENTER, it will exit from the shell.

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP 'command here'
```

Answer (score 1):

The script does not hang because there is no error message. It hangs because ssh is waiting for input from you. If you give ssh a command to run, as Henk showed, then ssh will run that command and then exit. If you do not give it a command, it will start an interactive shell. The shell prints a prompt (e.g. "$ ") and waits for you to type into it. You cannot see the prompt because you are sending all output to `/dev/null`.

Henk's code will make your script work, because if it succeeds in logging in, it will run a very short command and then return control to you.